# Converting asciinema output to gif

Tags: images, typescript, gif

Can I convert a `.json` file; generated by a program like [`asciinema`](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema); into an animated `.gif`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. While [asciinema](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema) doesn't provide this natively, there are tools out there that can facilitate that for you.

You can create your local recording like so:

```
asciinema rec my_recording.json
```

And then feed that into a tool like [asciicast2gif](https://github.com/pettarin/asciicast2gif):

```
./asciicast2gif my_recording.json my_recording.gif
```

Comment: `$ asciinema rec my_recording.json
asciinema: Too many arguments. See 'asciinema --help'.`

Comment: @user84207: I'm not sure what's going on; I just tested this on the latest version of asciinema (`1.4.0`) and it still seems to be working for me. If you run `asciinema` without any parameters (or `asciinema --help`), you should see almost the exact same command listed.

Comment: It was an older version

Comment: From a comment in the source code: `# run phantomjs to take screenshots while asciinema-player runs`. That's a pretty poor solution, oops! I would use a recording utility other than asciinema, like ttystudio.